# How to view the scan result for a specific build in SonarQube

Tags: jenkins, groovy, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline job that gets triggered once a merge request is created in gitlab. One of the stages in the pipeline is to do sonar analysis.

SonarQube shows the scan result for the latest build. Is there any way we can view the scan result for a specific build?

Here is the pipeline code that I use:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        gitLabConnection('my_connection')
        gitlabBuilds(builds: ["SonarQube"])
    }
    tools {
        maven 'maven'
        jdk 'jdk8'
    }

    stages {
        stage('SonarQube') {

            steps {
                gitlabCommitStatus("SonarQube") {
                    withSonarQubeEnv('my_sonar') {
                        sh "mvn sonar: sonar"
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to view this on the sonarqube project page under the "activity" tab